# Sysml - Internal Block Diagram with GEF in Eclipse JAVA

Tags: java, eclipse, diagram, sysml

I am currently working on a RCP-Application where i can draw an Internal-Block-Diagram.

Maybe most of you know "Papyrus" from eclipse. This modelling tool provides an Internal-Block-Diagram but I think it is a little bit overloaded so I decided to do it on my own.

I found this awesome tutorial : 
https://www.vainolo.com/tutorials/gef-tutorials/

It helped me a lot how GEF works but one thing is not explained. How to draw ports. In the picture below you can see what i am capable of.

[image: This is what i got and what i can do.]

I am trying to modify my application that a user is able to draw ports. Like in the next picture:
[image]

Does somebody know how this is done in GEF ?
As far as I understand it, it has something to do with the figure of a node. Every node has a figure which is displayed inside the diagram. A port is an extension of the edge of a node and it is not possible to exceed the edge of a node. So I think that papyrus uses a different way to make this happen.
I tried to get the source code of Papyrus but i found nothing neither a documentation about it...

I am thankfully for every opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Papyrus use [GMF](https://www.eclipse.org/modeling/gmp/) to create these ports. 
You may check classes with containing *BorderItem*, for example [AbstractBorderItemEditPart](https://github.com/eclipse/gmf-runtime/blob/master/org.eclipse.gmf.runtime.diagram.ui/src/org/eclipse/gmf/runtime/diagram/ui/editparts/AbstractBorderItemEditPart.java).

Be careful, the tutorial you are following seems to have been written for GEF3. 
As far as I know, there is no "easy" way to manage port in pure GEF3.

There was a major change in GEF last year, you should be able to easily create port with the new GEF4 API.

Comment: Thanks Benoit for your reply.
As you might notice, i am new to this kind of content and all i find of GMF is this tooling. But i don't want to use this kind of auto generation. 
Is there some good tutorial or starting point to develop such editor by myself ?

Comment: You can use connection decorations for a lightweight alternative to ports if you do not need advanced port behaviour. (Decoration example: https://github.com/eclipse/gef/blob/master/org.eclipse.gef.zest.examples.jface/src/org/eclipse/gef/zest/examples/jface/JFaceEdgeDecorationExample.java)